# A variable is declared as float f = 5.2 but while printing %d is used, I didn't get the o/p as 5 its printing some garbage value

Tags: c, unix

```
/* Compiled uisng GCC Compiler in CentOs 5   */

#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    float f = 5.2;
    printf("f = %d\n",f);
    return 0;
}

/*  O/p is not 5 its printing some garbage value  */
```

Why is the output not `5`?  What is the in-memory representation of float values?

Answer (score 7):

"`%d`" prints a decimal integer. This means `printf` is interpreting what gets passed as an integer, not a float. It's not doing any smart conversion and I'm pretty sure this is undefined behaviour.

The in memory representation of a float is implementation specific. Most implementations use [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), but this is not guaranteed at all.

For the record using "-Wall -Wextra" with gcc would have picked this mistake up as a warning. If you want to print it as an integer you must cast it too:

```
printf("f = %d\n",(int)f);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not printing `5` because you're not giving it `5`.  You're giving it `5.2`.  `5` is an integer value and `5.2` is a floating point value.  The first is typically encoded using 2s-complement while the second is typically encoded using IEEE floating point values.  (There are other encodings possible and even occasionally in use, but the two you're most likely to encounter are the two I've mentioned.)

If you're telling the computer that you're giving it an integer (`%d`) and then you proceed to give it a floating point value (`5.2`) getting garbage is what you expect.  It's taking the bits of IEEE floating point representation and reading them as if it were an integer.  (It's the old formula: garbage in, garbage out.)  If you try not lying to the computer you'll get better results.

The code you want to use in your `printf` call is `%f` instead of `%d`.  Using it means you're no longer lying to the computer about the type of the data being passed in.  That being said, to head off your inevitable next question, be sure to read [this explanation of floating point](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) so you understand why your floating point numbers aren't what you think they are.